# Access VBA To Save Table As Spreadsheet

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access-2013, excel-2013

I am using this syntax to export a table to a .xlsx file.  The issue that I Have is that anytime I try to open the file, this error is thrown:

> Excel cannot open the file because the file format or file extension is not valid.  Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file.

I am using Excel 2013 and Access 2013 - and this is the export line I use

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet transfertype:=acExport, spreadsheettype:=acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, TableName:=strTable, filename:=strWorksheetPath, hasfieldnames:=True
```

What is the way to export an access table to excel so you can open the file error free?

Comment: change this to a different file format spreadsheettype:=acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12,

Comment: @DougCoats - what should I change it to?  I thought 12 was for Excel 2013?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, strTable, strWorksheetPath, True
```